# Does Not Contain A Constructor That Takes 1 Arguments

Tags: c#, exception, invalidoperationexception

I am a bit new to C# and I recently ran into an issue receiving an "Invalid Operation Exception" when my serial connection is lost during a serial communication operation. I am trying to catch the error via `private void port_ErrorReceived` (see below) but I keep receiving an error stating "does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments".

```
    private void port_ErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool error = false;

        // Check if the comport is closed
        if (!comport.IsOpen)
        { 
                try
                {
                    // Try to open the port
                    comport.Open();
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
                catch (IOException) { error = true; }
                catch (ArgumentException) { error = true; }
                catch (InvalidOperationException) { error = true; }

                if (error) MessageBox.Show(this, "No serial port identified. Please check your connection.", "Serial Connection Lost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
         }     
    }
```

Here is where I call my new event handler:

```
     comport.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs(port_ErrorReceived);
```

I've seen some similar posts on StackOverflow but I wasn't quite sure what applied to this scenario. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean simply:

```
comport.ErrorReceived += port_ErrorReceived;
```

or more verbosely:

```
comport.ErrorReceived += new SerialErrorReceivedEventHandler(port_ErrorReceived);
```

(but they are identical; there's no reason not to use the first version)